# Using lib file csv.lib cause "list index out of range" error

Tags: python, windows, csv

I'm trying write the rows of the below columns using  csv lib (csv.writer) file in Python, but at the end of execution, a "list index out of range" error is generated. Is there any problem with the lib file I'm using?

```
for i in range(len(columns["E4_venus0_RW"])):
    try:
        writer.writerow((columns[CPU_RD_Total][i], columns[E4_VENUS0_RW][i], columns[MMClk][i]))
    except:
        writer.writerow((columns[CPU_RD_Total][i], columns[CPU_WR_Total][i], columns[CPU_Total], "", "", "", "", "" ))
```

Comment: Can you properly paste the code, its not readable.

Comment: Use code field, to properly indent the code.

Comment: i think its good now thanks @jontahan

Answer (score 0):

No, this doesn't seems to be a problem with the library you are using. This *"list index out of range"* error is generated when you are trying to access the list index, which is not there in the list. For eg,

```
list1 = ['a','b']
```

This is a list with 2 elements, with index 0 and 1,

```
print(list1[0]) //a
print(list1[1]) //b
```

But, if you will try to access list1[2] element, it will throw *list index out of range* error.
In your case, the problem is similar to this only.

Comment: writing  a csv file with above columns, will it need an empty csv file with specific column length(like the range value I'm giving in the above loop)?

Comment: Yes, you need to make sure that you are trying to access the existing index only.